# Как спарсить текст постов из Instagram по username?

Tags: python, парсер, instagram, instagram-api

Требуется спарсить текст постов Instagram. На данный момент реализовал [по этому видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGU2X5lrz9M)  вход через логинопароль и переход по ссылке к нужному username'у, но не понимаю, как действовать дальше. Как можно получить *текст* всех постов со страницы и возможно ли это вообще? Код прилагаю.

```
from selenium import webdriver   
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary


username = USERNAME
password = PASSWORD



class InstagramBot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def classBrowser(self):
        self.driver.close()


    def login(self):

        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")
        time.sleep(2)

        login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher']")
        login_button.click()
        time.sleep(2)

        user_name_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
        user_name_elem.clear()
        user_name_elem.send_keys(self.username)

        password_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
        password_elem.clear()
        password_elem.send_keys(self.password)
        password_elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(2)


    def get_posts(self, hashtag):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/" + hashtag + "/")
        time.sleep(2)


andreyIG = InstagramBot(username, password)
andreyIG.login()
andreyIG.get_posts('cats_of_instagram')
```

Comment: В вашем коде нету каких-либо попыток что-либо сделать. Вы просто перешли на страницу и ожидаете 2 секунды и все.

Comment: Ищите элементы по XPath или CSS-селектору